# Get the result of following query:-

Tags: mysql

```
select sum(total1) + SELECT sum( total2 )
from balance WHERE id=( SELECT max(id) 
FROM balance)
```

Can't seem to get it working

Comment: looks like you have mismatched parenthesis.  there is no '(' , for your last ')'

Comment: I don't see PHP and javascript here

Comment: My bad ,removed them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
select sum(totalSEK) + MAX(id) As totalSum FROM balance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
select sum(total1+total2) as total from balance WHERE id=( SELECT max(id) FROM balance)
```

Comment: i wanted to add the sum of TOTAL1 + the last record that was inserted into  TOTAL2 thats why i had the WHERE id=( SELECT max(id) FROM balance)

Comment: tried like this but still getting error :select sum(totalSEK) from balance WHERE id=( SELECT max(id) FROM balance) + sum(totalUSD)

Answer (score 0):

select ((select sum(total1) from balance) + (select sum(total2) from balance WHERE id=( SELECT max(id) FROM balance)) ) as totalSums